# Chain rule expanding of random variables

Tags: probability

$P(X_4, X_3, X_2, X_1) = P(X_4 | X_3, X_2, X_1) \cdot P(X_3 | X_2, X_1) \cdot P(X_2 | X_1) \cdot P(X_1)$

Given this example how can I further simplify this to get rid of all the commas like make this: $P(X_4 | X_3, X_2, X_1)$ something like $P(X_4 | a) \cdot P(X_3 | b)$. Wiki had no other simplification but for an assignment im doing its necessary and im at a stump

Comment: Nope.  That's as simple as it gets unless you are not telling us about conditional independences between the events.

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes they have conditional dependences for each